# Methods from Tree::TreeNode not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a question about ruby gems. I'm writing some code in ruby and I want to use a tree. I decided to use the `Tree::TreeNode` class. See here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/evolve75/RubyTree/Tree/TreeNode for documentation.

This is my first time using a gem. I ran `sudo gem install tree` in the terminal and added `require 'tree'` to the beginning of my ruby file. For the most part it works. I can initialize nodes and most of the methods work. However, some methods such as `#each_leaf` and `#children` don't work. Here's example code:

```
require 'tree'
node1 = Tree::TreeNode.new('node1',1)
node2 = Tree::TreeNode.new('node2',2)
node1.add(node2)
node1.each_leaf { |node| puts "name: #{node.name}, content: #{node.content}"}
```

When I run it I get the following error message:

```
test.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `each_leaf' for #<Tree::TreeNode:0x007fc2a905e560> (NoMethodError)
```

but when I run the code with `each_leaf` replaced by `each` it works perfectly (of course I get info for nodes 1 and 2, whereas if it worked `each_leaf` should only get me the info for node 2).

Looking through the documentation for `TreeNode` I've noticed that all the methods that don't work for me are listed next to `Tree::TreeNode+` rather than `Tree::TreeNode`. I haven't been able to figure out what this means. Do I have to do something extra or install some other gem to get those methods? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I wonder if the `tree` gem is the gem you're looking for. The method is there when I look at the source on github and has been there for years. I can't figure out what the `<sup>+</sup>` mean on rubydoc.info either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the version of the gem on rubygems.org lags behind the latest version on github (from which the documentation is generated). You can install the github version using:

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree.git
```

or just add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'tree', github: 'evolve75/RubyTree'
```

**Update**: looks like it does have the latest version on rubygems, but it's renamed to rubytree, hence

```
gem uninstall tree
gem install rubytree
```

but `require 'tree'` as you did before.